# Kivy Button widget : Attribute Error, has no attribute 'fbind'

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, anaconda, kivy-language

I'm trying to find the solution to a problem since two or three hours, but I just can't find what is going wrong, exactly, even when looking at other user's problems here on SO or in the Kivy documentation.

I am currently following a few tutorials online, and got to toy around with [this simple one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBUi2HrC-F0)

My code doesn't exactly match his, but even while replicating the exact code of this tutorial as a test, I get the exact same error, related to the Button widget in Kivy:

```
AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'fbind'
```

Could this be related to an installation problem of some kind ? Can anyone help me solve this ?

```
[INFO              ] Kivy v1.8.0
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\NoirFluo\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-03-01_64.txt
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 157 symbols loaded
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=Nones
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pygame, img_pil, img_gif 
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60s
[DEBUG             ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600s
[DEBUG             ] [App         ] Loading kv <C:/Users/NoirFluo/Desktop/Python/Kivy/TestProblemButton\screens.kv>
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Ignored <egl_rpi> (import error)
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Display driver windib
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual window size: 800x600
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual color bits r8 g8 b8 a8
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual depth bits: 24
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual stencil bits: 8
[DEBUG             ] [Window      ] Actual multisampling samples: 2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <4.5.13464 Compatibility Profile Context 21.19.407.0>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <ATI Technologies Inc.>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 5
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <4.50>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[DEBUG             ] [Shader      ] Fragment compiled successfully
[DEBUG             ] [Shader      ] Vertex compiled successfully
[DEBUG             ] [ImagePygame ] Load <C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\data\glsl\default.png>
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
GLEW initialization succeeded

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-414e3aba4aa1>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/NoirFluo/Desktop/Python/Kivy/TestProblemButton/main.py', wdir='C:/Users/NoirFluo/Desktop/Python/Kivy/TestProblemButton')

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/NoirFluo/Desktop/Python/Kivy/TestProblemButton/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    ScreensApp().run()

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 766, in run
    root = self.build()

  File "C:/Users/NoirFluo/Desktop/Python/Kivy/TestProblemButton/main.py", line 23, in build
    return Manager()

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 791, in __init__
    super(ScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 66, in __init__
    super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 63, in __init__
    super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 173, in __init__
    Builder.apply(self)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1566, in apply
    self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1672, in _apply_rule
    self.apply(child)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1566, in apply
    self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1670, in _apply_rule
    child = cls(__no_builder=True)

  File "C:\Users\NoirFluo\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.fbind('state', self.cancel_event)

AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'fbind'`
```

Here is the code from the screens.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

<ScreenOne>:
    Button:
        text: "On SCREEN 1 >> Go to Screen 2"
        on_press: root.manager.current = "screen2"

<ScreenTwo>:
    Button:
        text: "On SCREEN 2 >> Go to Screen 3"
        on_press: root.manager.current = "screen3"

<ScreenThree>:
    Button:
        text: "On SCREEN 3 >> Go to Screen 1"
        on_press: root.manager.current = "screen1"


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager

    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two
    screen_three: screen_three

    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: "screen1"
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: "screen2"
        manager: screen_manager

    ScreenThree:
        id: screen_three
        name: "screen3"
        manager: screen_manager
```

Here is the code of main.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class ScreenThree(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_three = ObjectProperty(None)

class ScreensApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Manager()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScreensApp().run()
```

edit : Mhh, the editor has eaten my "Hello, folks !", and I can't seem to put it back by editing my post, for some reasons, so I'll put it here : Hello, guys ! ^^'

Comment: out of topic, but why do you use kivy 1.8.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy 1.8.0 is a dinosaur, soon there'll be a newer version than the current old-ish stable (1.9.1).

I've tried your code and it works fine, also, I believe it worked even on 1.8.0 without problems (not sure, check closed [issues](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues) if you want).

Now you can do one of these actions:

- completely reinstall your Kivy installation from the tag you want to use (if it's 1.8.0, well go for it)
- install stable version
- install latest Kivy version

Check the [instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html) on how to do so and if it's not enough or too hard, use [this installer](https://github.com/KeyWeeUsr/KivyInstaller). Just a note, this **IS NOT!** the same thing as `kivy.bat` you have now(there was such a file in 1.8.0 package, it's not here anymore), so it won't work as a replacement for the old one.